# get all data from two SQL table with a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query below which creates a join between the two table which is working fint but i would Like to also show all the data which is in "T" that doesnt appear in D. this only Show the Twwet Id which come in both, can I also show the Ones Which dont Apper in D but do in T

```
SELECT     
  t.ClientId,  
  t.PageName, 
  t.Country, 
  t.CreatedAt,
  t.TweetId,
  t.TweetMessage, 
  t.Replied, 
  t.RetweetCount, 
  t.FavoritedCount, 
  t.en_Media_type, 
  Sum(d.FollowersCount) As TotalFollowers
FROM dbo.[Tweets(HT)] AS t
INNER JOIN dbo.RetweetersData AS d ON d.TweetID = t.TweetId
WHERE t.ClientId = 54 
GROUP BY t.ClientId,  
  t.PageName, 
  t.Country, 
  t.CreatedAt,
  t.TweetId,
  t.TweetMessage, 
  t.Replied, 
  t.RetweetCount, 
  t.FavoritedCount, 
  t.en_Media_type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
INNER JOIN dbo.RetweetersData ...
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.RetweetersData ...
```

See [this explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to use Left join instead of Inner join
try following

```
SELECT     
  t.ClientId,  
  t.PageName, 
  t.Country, 
  t.CreatedAt,
  t.TweetId,
  t.TweetMessage, 
  t.Replied, 
  t.RetweetCount, 
  t.FavoritedCount, 
  t.en_Media_type, 
  Sum(d.FollowersCount) As TotalFollowers
FROM dbo.[Tweets(HT)] AS t
Left JOIN dbo.RetweetersData AS d ON d.TweetID = t.TweetId
WHERE t.ClientId = 54 
GROUP BY t.ClientId,  
  t.PageName, 
  t.Country, 
  t.CreatedAt,
  t.TweetId,
  t.TweetMessage, 
  t.Replied, 
  t.RetweetCount, 
  t.FavoritedCount, 
  t.en_Media_type
```